# Include .json data in javascript code (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

My personal website is not letting me upload a .json file that needs to be read by a javascript code. I need to include the data from that .json file in the body.

I'm using this code to read and use the .json file:

```
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, flare) {
  if (error) throw error;

  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});
```

But, since I need to embed the json data into the script I don't know how to do this.

My .json file looks like this:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
```

Comment: You just need to hardcode that JSON in a variable named `flare` and remove `d3.json` function (leaving its callback).

Answer (score 1):

You could just embed your json in to your js since JSON is just an object.

```
var flare = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  };


  root = flare;
  root.x0 = height / 2;
  root.y0 = 0;

  function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
  }

  root.children.forEach(collapse);
  update(root);
});
```